# WebBrowser Control Navigation Back

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is it possible to Navigate back in the WebBrowser Control? I couldnt find any method to do this.

Comment: Shahar Prish was right, I did always an WebBrowser.InvokeScript by using "eval".

Comment: Both are right, but i already implemented the Version by Pharao2k so he deserves the Credit :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no current way to do this from cache. But you can override the Key-Back Function to catch the back-button-press and implement your own Stack of Sites you visit.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do `WebBrowser.InvokeScript()` to call `window.history.back()` and cause the browser to go back in that way.

Comment: Just for the Archive. The complete Call would be: WebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval","window.history.back()");