# MAke a website section in Windows phone 8 App built with Windows Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Hello guys please i built an app with windows phone studio, but they do not have a website section, to open a website within my app( not linking to default browser, but withing the app) So please how can i add a new page for this website section in the app using visual studio, and i need the website navigate with back button, cos i tried one that shows the website, but no matter how deep i navigate into the website, once i click the back button on my phone, it closes/exits  the app.

Thanks and much appreciate your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `WebBrowser` control. You can check
[Windows Phone Developer Blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/09/17/windows-phone-webbrowser-control-tips.aspx) for more information on usage of `WebBrowser` control. For Navigation using back button, you can check these links:
[1.WebBrowser Control Navigation Back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981765/webbrowser-control-navigation-back)
[2.How to handle a Web Browser back and forward navigation in a WP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704998/how-to-handle-a-web-browser-back-and-forward-navigation-in-a-wp7-app)

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks alot vasuy, but i have been trying them and the back button on the phone still exits app, instead of going back to previous browser page...